# Angular2 change detection on website

Tags: angular, typescript

I am stuck at designing an Angular2 app that detects changes on another website.

Right now my service looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AlexaService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

getPrevQuery() {

                return this.http.get('https://example.com/alexa/lastQuery.html');
        }

}
```

And the component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlexaService } from './alexa.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alexa',
  templateUrl: './alexa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alexa.component.css']
})
export class AlexaComponent implements OnInit {

  data;
  constructor(service: AlexaService) {
        service.getPrevQuery()
        .subscribe(
                (response: Response) => {
                        this.data = response.text();
                        console.log(this.data);
                        },
                (error) => console.log(error)
                );

}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

One thing I could do is periodically check the https://example.com/alexa/lastQuery.html. But the real intention is to make changes in the view when a change occurs in the lastQuery.html. Can we do this with Observables?

Comment: Is `lastQuery.html` a page outside your Angular application (some other web site)? An observable doesn't observe a website, an observable allows you to subscribe to events that your code fires.

Comment: *One thing I could do is periodically check the `https://example.com/alexa/lastQuery.html`*: there's nothing else you can do, unless `https://example.com/alexa/lastQuery.html` notifies your app every time it changes. You can of course use Observables to poll a website on a regular basis. Using interval(), for example.

Comment: Yes, `lastQuery.html` is outside my angular app. So, if I need to periodically check the same, the interval has to be very small close to 0 maybe

Comment: Spamming example.com with endless consecutive queries is probably on of the best ways to get blacklisted out of example.com.